# Model Validation - Must have at least one of two attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have a model in which two fields are validated, but only one of them is mandatory.

I wrote the following validation, but it's not working:

```
  validates_presence_of :results, :on => :update, :if => Proc.new { |order| order.results_image? }
  validates_presence_of :results_image, :on => :update, :if => Proc.new { |order| order.results? }
```

Comment: "It's not working" is the least helpful thing you could tell us. What is it doing? What did you expect it to do? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: There is no information about the fact that something has gone wrong, let This message shows up on the field to be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a custom validate method that adds to the errors collection if both are blank but passes if either is filled...

```
def validate 
    errors.add_to_base "one or other is required" if results.blank? and results_image.blank? 
end
```